# Building a paragraph in Apps script

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Not really sure why (Not really true: it's because I'm embryonic as a coder and not refined enough), but I can't even save this part of my code set.

I'm simply identifying an existing piece of text "##XXXX##" in a Google doc template, then replacing it with a paragraph consisting of text and imported text from a spreadsheet.

I'm sure the problem is in the body.insertParagraph, because I'm dynamically building the paragraph as I insert it. But how else can this be done?

```
var foundTag = body.findText("##XXXX##");
var tagElement = foundTag.getElement();
var parent = tagElement.getParent();
var insertPoint = parent.getParent().getChildIndex(parent);

// Build the paragraph to insert

var songBlock = body.insertParagraph(insertpoint, {
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var songName = String(dataArray[i][1]);
    var sWs = String(dataArray[i][2]);
    var pub =  String(dataArray[i][3]);
    appendText("Song Name:" + brk);
    appendText(songName + brk);
    appendText("Songwriter(s):" + brk);
    appendText(sWs + brk);
    appendText("Publisher(s):" + brk);
    appendText(pub + brk);
    appendHorizontalRule();
    appendText(brk);
}
```

Comment: There is something really wrong with how you treat the `for` loop here - statements can't be values and certainly cannot be object properties. You should read up on [`insertProject()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-paragraph) documentation and what the method accepts in its parameters. Also closing parenthesis is missing. To sum up - the syntax is invalid. Please, always include error messages if you seek debugging help (but I bet it is related to `SyntaxError` in this case)

Comment: I read the InsertParagraph documentation, but I'm not sure what you mean beyond that. In my question above, I said I think the issue is that I'm trying to build the paragraph where the second argument is a paragraph. That said, I'm not sure if you mean something beyond that. I will try to create the paragraph prior to the insert statement.

Comment: So, I figure it out. I don't think this is the best way to do it, but it works (in terms of building the insertion.

I just build the text insertion like:

 songBlock = (songBlock + "Song Name:" + brk);

Comment: Ezra, glad to you figured it out - well, I meant exactly what you did - move the loop out of the context where it is forbidden and pass the dynamic text or dynamically appended instance of `Paragraph`. Btw, you do not need `String()` constructor - when concatenated with strings, values will be coerced to strings

Comment: Yeah, i know. i just casted as strings, just in case. in some languages (or experiences) the compiler can be lazy or mis-trustful. So, I guarded my butt.

Comment: Ezra, as you know, JavaScript is very eager in assuming everything for you :) You safe here as long as you remember the rule: when performing addition, if at least one value is a string, it will be coerced to string (and textual data from a cell will be always of type string as well - this one on GAS, though)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following code:

```
// Prepare to write song data
var foundTag = body.findText("##XXXX##");
Logger.log('found it', foundTag);
var tagElement = foundTag.getElement();
var parent = tagElement.getParent();
var insertPoint = parent.getParent().getChildIndex(parent);
var text = body.editAsText();
var songBlock = "\n"

// Build the text to insert

    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var songName = String(dataArray[i][1]);
    var sWs = String(dataArray[i][2]);
    var pub =  String(dataArray[i][3]);
    songBlock = (songBlock + "Song Name:" + brk);
    songBlock = (songBlock + songName + brk);
    songBlock = (songBlock + "Songwriter(s):" + brk);
    songBlock = (songBlock + sWs + brk);
    songBlock = (songBlock + "Publisher(s):" + brk);
    songBlock = (songBlock + pub + brk);
    songBlock = (songBlock + brk);
}       

// Insert text at the beginning of the document.
text.insertText(insertPoint, songBlock);
```

The problem is now inserting, but that's for another post.